# DOM events for popup.html browser action - chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using my popup-page as options page - I can send info to the contentscript and retrieve back, BUT none DOM events in the popup window works.
I tried adding onClick events, I've tried with domelement.addEventListener('click', function, false) - Nothing works.
BUT everything works perfectly if I just open popup.html in a tab.
It's weird, because normal javascript which loads when popup.html has been loaded. I tested with a window.alert when document load. setTimeout doesn't work either, btw.
I can't seem to find anyone else with a similar problem?
The HTML and CSS of the popup page works just fine...

Snippet of manifest file:

```
"browser_action": {  
"default_icon": "icon.png",  
"popup": "popup.html"  
},
```

Comment: Sounds like a misunderstanding of [manifest version 2](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifestVersion.html). When `"manifest_version": 2` is set, the Content [Security Policy (CSP)](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) is activated. Inline scripts, string-to-JavaScript (`eval`, `setTimeout("string", .. )`), etc. will not execute.

Comment: So should I have manifest_version 1 or 2? I do not need to support <= v.17.

Comment: Set `"manifest_version":2`, and rewrite your code such that it runs correctly. I have provided the relevant documentation for it, so you should be able to fix the problem.

Comment: Okay thank you. Could you write that as an answer instead of a comment, so I can mark it solved.